# Capitalization and hyphenation in words like 'southeastern'

Tags: spelling, hyphens, capitalization

Is it

> South-Eastern Ukraine,
>
> Southeastern Ukraine, *or*
>
> South Eastern Ukraine

? What about capitalization? I saw various spellings. Which one is the most advisable? Don't close the question.

Comment: Hyphens and spaces are optional, and vary by style guide. Capitalisation rules vary between style guides. but the general principle is that if it is just a general region it will have a lower-case compass-point, whereas if it is a region specifically defined by officialdom or by an organisation whose definition is being used, it will have upper case. So south-east Ukraine but North Korea.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why is it different in Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Ukraine

Comment: Styles vary. There is not one single rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing the name of a country or place which is prefixed with a direction, it is preferable to write the direction name together, without a hyphen followed by the proper noun.

E.g: [Southeast Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southeast_Asia) or [Northeast India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_India) and many more...

However, when writing the direction alone in a sentence, you can use all small-caps along with a hyphen.

E.g: The dead strewn around the **north-west** and **south-east** walls.

For more reference [read this article](https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/north-south-west-east-capitalizing-can-be-a-beast).

Coming back to your question, first one is incorrect, second one correct, and third one incorrect.